# What are some strategies for beating the Snake (MGS1) Alternative/VR Missions?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty

I'm going for the "Virtually Impossible" achievement in Metal Gear Solid 2: Sons of Liberty HD.

What are some strategies for beating the final hardest (Snake (MGS1)) Alternative/VR Missions? They're near impossible!

Comment: Closed as per [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15888/does-i-can-only-answer-this-with-videos-suggest-a-question-is-too-broad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: Before you downvote this answer for being “link only”, please consider for a moment that it’s impossible for an answer to contain the contents of 48 videos!*

Firstly, here's the complete breakdown of missions you will be facing in this final stage:

**SNAKE (MGS1)** (available when Snake (Tuxedo) is 100%)

*VR MISSIONS*
Sneaking - Sneaking x 10
Sneaking - Eliminate All x 10
Weapon Mode x 40
Variety Mode x 3

*ALTERNATIVE MISSIONS*
Bomb Disposal Mode x 5
Elimination Mode x 10
Hold-up Mode x 10

Total = **88 missions**

**Bonus:** I've created a [mission tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z-70QB1ocvrfhCX5PZPvikhLTz2MTt9cosbyuZ5LgiY/edit?usp=sharing) so you can keep track of your overall progress through **all 511 missions**, too.

Unfortunately there are no general tips or tricks I can share. The missions themselves build upon everything the previous **423** missions have taught you. I could say that playing on XBox 360 is marginally easier due to its controller changes. And that hammering Triangle/Y is a good way to grab onto ledges. But it's mainly about taking that knowledge and skill you've developed up until this point and applying it. Sorry!

There are videos showing people completing these levels, but unfortunately they're usually people showing off their madskillz. Luckily there are a series of I've been able to find that explain how to complete each level in an easy-to-follow manner, without requiring patience-shattering super-skills.

(Credit to **Ash Treezy** (Dat Boi Treezy) for making them.)

I wish I could summarise their contents for this answer, but it's impossible. I used these videos to get the achievement myself on PS3 and XBox 360. They are easily the best resources I have found, official or unofficial.

### VR Missions

**SNEAKING**
[Sneaking 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gTFOWVxpHQ)
[Sneaking 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gTFOWVxpHQ) (same video as above - just further in)
[Sneaking 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecERdIennkM)
[Sneaking 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKq1ugg9bx8)
[Sneaking 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lr68V2H0HM)
[Sneaking 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olaKGR80vCY)
[Sneaking 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ5IzQxRyvI)
[Sneaking 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PP62RZjuAI)
[Sneaking 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zij_52b1U2A)
[Sneaking 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V44UX9yeOgo)

**ELIMINATE ALL**
[Eliminate All 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8WqVEfMmN4)
[Eliminate All 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1K_nMHkr0N4)
[Eliminate All 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xImKD7TWn5A)
[Eliminate All 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_nvl3INVZ8)
[Eliminate All 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvZ66ZDvndM)
[Eliminate All 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rp7eCFF7Vnc)
[Eliminate All 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjY-cWDK2rE&t=27s)
[Eliminate All 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND-KyhyNERY)
[Eliminate All 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnPgBwKWl4M)
[Eliminate All 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gzkeZwnpr0)

**WEAPON MODE**

**VARIETY MODE**
[Variety 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1S1GJS5osc)
[Variety 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRLoDAm24cg)
[Variety 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnhxDWIYfQ)

### Alternative Missions

**BOMB DISPOSAL**
[Bomb Disposal 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDizv69WKkw)
[Bomb Disposal 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqjyfjXh6UY)
[Bomb Disposal 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOEbS6z9OTw)
[Bomb Disposal 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alp2a6DUC0Y)
[Bomb Disposal 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKKFUwuHVug)

**ELIMINATION**
[Elimination 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtv99njQTPY)
[Elimination 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI3r9AYBh6c)
[Elimination 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj2ZGhjB_Hg)
[Elimination 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT4m0dSq7ko)
[Elimination 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J9tZoth1Xs)
[Elimination 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvcV3vDqx3A)
[Elimination 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teRwG-8nttM)
[Elimination 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vG_CIRyc9tg)
[Elimination 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofyCQwfiqOg)
[Elimination 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz6ffU4wPZ4)

**HOLD-UP**
[Hold-up 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGBPHfqY2PY)
[Hold-up 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHBwM5KPhco)
[Hold-up 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHNaQlVPVTY)
[Hold-up 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAU3Vo73ml4)
[Hold-up 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lu4mIQGvMmY)
[Hold-up 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNonl3LO2eE)
[Hold-up 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9_ybqtaUZM)
[Hold-up 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3ZQGL6jqW0)
[Hold-up 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8YRVMEQNIA)
[Hold-up 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2qcyvP1BaM)